# Use Cmd+P / save as PDF to save many page of website as PDFs - using one of R, JavaScript

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, rselenium

Being able to quickly and easily visit many pages of our website, and save those pages as local PDFs, is essential for a feature we're building into our app. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68447289/with-rselenium-how-to-save-webpage-as-a-pdf-using-print-save) on the topic was marked as duplicate, and so I wanted to adjust the question:

We have a website that:

- has a login to get through
- has 100s of pages we'd like to visit and save as PDFs

Rather than using some complex JS PDF library for this, we're leveraging chrome's built in Cmd+P to launch print panel and then **Destination: Save as PDF** to save the entire webpage as a single PDF file. Our website is built so that pages save neatly to PDF using the browsers built-in save-to-pdf functionality.

What is the best way to automate this process over 100s of URLs? We can very easily, in R or JS, create an array of the 100s of different page URLs that need to be visited. Is RSelenium a smart approach for this, like how it's used in the hyperlink? We are currently stuck with RSelenium as the linked answer in that question is not working for us. We are able to launch the print panel, however we cannot use RSelenium to click the **Destination** toggle nor the **save** button in the print panel.

Perhaps there is an easier way to do this using JavaScript?

**Edit:** I've given Mac's **Automator** a try, and have figured out how to open multiple pages at once. However it's not clear how to then automatically save the pages to PDF. It also doesn't seem sound to have 100s of tabs all open at the same time in browser.

[image]

Comment: I'd use AutoHotKey

Comment: can we use this on a Mac

Comment: Not that I know of https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=27043#:~:text=Re%3A%20Autohotkey%20for%20Mac,-Post%20by%20RickC&text=Unfortunately%20AutoHotkey%20cannot%20be%20used,in%20programs%20%2D%20Automator%20and%20AppleScript. Automator and AppleScript might be usable. But I know it could be done in Windows in only a few minutes

Comment: How about https://github.com/alvarcarto/url-to-pdf-api ?